# Parsing a unicode encoded string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

So I have this string received from an API I'm working with:

```
\x7B\x22country\x22\x3A\x22US\x22\x7D
```

For some absurd reason they encode their responses... Don't ask me why. When I receive this data in NodeJS (v11.7.0), I'm trying to encode it to JSON.

Using Javascript on my browser I can encode this simply by doing JSON.parse(), but NodeJS isn't behaving the same way. I get this error if I try to do:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(response));
```

*Note: The response variable is the direct body from the API response*

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 0
```

I tried this as well with the following error:

```
console.log(JSON.parse("\""+response+"\""));
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 2
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I convert this to a json object?

Comment: Do you have an example of the response?

Comment: @SilvioBiasiol Yessir, the response is at the top of the post. "\x7B\x22country\x22\x3A\x22US\x22\x7D"

Comment: Working well with node 8.14.0 : https://i.imgur.com/iBjSNlx.png

Comment: Also works for me, Node.js v 11.7.0 `JSON.parse('\x7B\x22country\x22\x3A\x22US\x22\x7D')` -> `{ country: 'US' }`

Comment: Have you tried convert response to buffer and then `JSON.parse()` ? Like this `JSON.parse(new Buffer.from(response))`

Comment: Are you sure you need to add double quotes around your string ? `const st = "\x7B\x22country\x22\x3A\x22US\x22\x7D"; console.log(JSON.parse(st));` runs fine with node v11.8.0.

Comment: As a literal `'\x7B\x22country\x22\x3A\x22US\x22\x7D' == '{"country":"US"}'` but OP is getting it from an API so its not a string literal .